# Couldn't find Manufacturer with 'id'= (blank)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create a web application to practise my Ruby on Rails skill. I have a few entities in my database `manufacturers, models, tints, prices`

- manufacturers `{id, name}` - stores the make of the car
- models `{id, manufacturer_id, name}` - stores the models of the car
- tints `{id, manufacturer_id, model_id, front, sides, rear}` - stores the length of tint required
- prices `{id, description, price }` - stores the price of the item

I created a page to generate a quotation for window tinting. The page includes drop-down menus to let user to select `manufacturer, model, type of film(front), type of film(side+rear)`

Below is the code for the form

```
<%= form_tag('/quotation/tints/generate') do %>
    <%= label :manufacturer_id, 'Manufacturer' %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= collection_select(:tint, :manufacturer_id, Manufacturer.order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Manufacturer"}) %> 
    </div>

    Model:
    <div class="field">
    <%= grouped_collection_select(:tint, :model_id, Manufacturer.order(:name), :models, :name, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Model"}) %> 
    </div>

    <%= label :price_front, 'Front Tint' %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= collection_select(:price, :price_front, Price.order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Front Tint"}) %> 
    </div>

    <%= label :price_rear, 'Size and Back Tint' %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= collection_select(:price, :price_rear, Price.order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Side & Rear Tint"}) %> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

When the form is submitted, it should be redirected to `/quotation/tints/generate` and display the value from the dropdown menu. However, I received an error, saying that `Couldn't find Manufacturer with 'id'=`. The code that caused the error is shown below

```
def generate
  @manufacturers = Manufacturer.find(params[:manufacturer_id])
end
```

Here is the parameter from the debug log

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Pl2bXiRT0AoF4i0h1RCHDbuvaKJNZOkV5ULQHKxDQgZzBWWLJ2mH7ddb9akwgxbloxBIHoVaT3pcwoIGcRufpg==",
 "tint"=>{"manufacturer_id"=>"7", "model_id"=>"6"},
 "price"=>{"price_front"=>"1", "price_rear"=>"2"},
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

I can see that the `id` of each drop down value are shown up correctly in the parameter list. However, I coundn't able to print the value at `/quotation/tints/generate` nor get the name of the manufacturer or model.

Here is `routes.rb`:

```
get '/quotation/tints' => 'tints#quotation', :as => 'tints_quotation'
post '/quotation/tints/generate' => 'tints#generate', :as => 'generate_tints_quotation'
```

`Tint.rb`:

```
class Tint < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :manufacturers
  has_many :models
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  belongs_to :model

  validates_uniqueness_of :model_id, :scope => [:manufacturer_id]
end
```

`Model.rb`:

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manufacturer, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => [:manufacturer_id]

  before_save :capitalize_content
end
```

`Manufacruter.rb`:

```
class Manufacturer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :models, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :name, :presence => true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  before_save :capitalize_content
end
```

`tints.controller.rb`:

```
def quotation
  render 'quotation'
end

def generate
  @manufacturers = Manufacturer.find(params[:manufacturer_id])
end
```

`generate.html.erb`:

```
<%= @manufacturers.name %>
```

I'm trying to print the manufacturer selected

I have tried multiple ways to define it, but I am still facing the same error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are those your only routes in routes.rb?

Comment: Nope, there are more. `Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :prices
  resources :tints
  resources :models
  resources :manufacturers
  devise_for :users
  get '/quotation/tints' => 'tints#quotation', :as => 'tints_quotation'
  post '/quotation/tints/generate' => 'tints#generate', :as => 'generate_tints_quotation'
    # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root "pages#show", page: "index"
  
end
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your params, `manufacturer_id` is a nested value of `tint`, as opposed to being a direct key of the params hash. Try the following:

```
def generate
  @manufacturers = Manufacturer.find(params[:tint][:manufacturer_id])
end
```

Comment: Can you please give me some clue how can I print the `front, side, and rear` values from the `tints` table? This is what I did, `@manufacturers = Manufacturer.find(params[:tint][:manufacturer_id])`, `@models = Model.find(params[:tint][:model_id])`, and I tried to filter the table using where clause, `@measurements = Tint.where('manufacturer_id' => @manufacturers).where('model_id' => @models)`. I tried to do `<%= @measurements.front %>`, and I received `undefined method `front' for #<Tint::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000102e7e48>`

Comment: Please ask new questions by posting a new question. Stack Overflow uses a Q&A format, meaning one question, one accepted answer. Unfortunately, this format means that rolling discussions covering multiple related issues isn't a good fit.